# Innovative menu Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop-1.5, megamenu

I have installed innovative menu (mega menu) in prestashop 1.5.6.2 shop,In BO when i tried to create a new menu, the ajax load and get me with this result

```
{"configure":false,"view":null}
```

The create button call this function

```
function editMenu(idMenu)
{
    show_innovativemenu_activity = true;
    $.ajax({
            data: {employee_id_lang : employee_id_lang, token : token,     innovativemenu_action : 'editMenu', id_menu : idMenu},
            success: function(msg){
                    msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                    $("div.configure_menu").html(msg.configure);

                    if(parseInt(idMenu))
                            $("div.view_menu").html(msg.view);
                    else $("div.view_menu").html('');
                    }
    });
```

}

the call is like that :  [image] Create new menu

The ajax calls this php function

```
 public function editMenu($id_menu = null, $ajax = true)
    {
            global $smarty;
            if (is_numeric($id_menu) AND ((int)$id_menu) > 0)
                    $menu = new Innovative_Menu((int)$id_menu);
            else $menu = new Innovative_Menu();

            $text_column_title_font_style = $text_column_title_font_weight = $text_column_title_font_size = $text_column_title_font_family =
            $text_block_font_size = $text_block_font_family = $text_block_font_weight = $text_block_font_style =  
            $text_menu_font_style = $text_menu_font_family = $text_menu_font_size = $text_menu_font_weight = $text_column_list_font_style_hover = $text_column_list_font_weight_hover = '';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_column_title_font_size as $font)
                    $text_column_title_font_size .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_title_font_size ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_weight as $font)
                    $text_column_title_font_weight .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_title_font_weight ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_style as $font)
                    $text_column_title_font_style .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_title_font_style ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Font_Family::get(true) as $font)
                    $text_column_title_font_family .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_title_font_family ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_style as $font)
                    $text_column_list_font_style_hover .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_list_font_style_hover ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_weight as $font)
                    $text_column_list_font_weight_hover .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->column_list_font_weight_hover ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_size as $font)
                    $text_block_font_size .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->block_font_size ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_weight as $font)
                    $text_block_font_weight .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->block_font_weight ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_style as $font)
                    $text_block_font_style .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->block_font_style ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Font_Family::get(true) as $font)
                    $text_block_font_family .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->block_font_family ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';


            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_style as $font)
                    $text_menu_font_style .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->font_style ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Font_Family::get(true) as $font)
                    $text_menu_font_family .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->font_family ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_size as $font)
                    $text_menu_font_size .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->font_size ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';

            foreach (Innovative_Menu::$all_font_weight as $font)
                    $text_menu_font_weight .= '<option value="'.$font.'" '.($font == $menu->font_weight ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$font.'</option>';


            $default_language = (int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            $display_flags = $this->displayFlags($languages, $default_language, 'home_text', 'home_text', true);

            $smarty->assign(array(
                    'edit_menu' => true,
                    'menu' => $menu,
                    'tabs_of_menu' => $this->getTabsOfMenu($menu->id),
                    'admin_img' => _PS_ADMIN_IMG_,
                    'text_block_font_style' => self::cleanHTML($text_block_font_style),
                    'text_block_font_family' => self::cleanHTML($text_block_font_family),
                    'text_block_font_weight' => self::cleanHTML($text_block_font_weight),
                    'text_block_font_size' => self::cleanHTML($text_block_font_size),
                    'text_menu_font_style' => self::cleanHTML($text_menu_font_style),
                    'text_menu_font_family' => self::cleanHTML($text_menu_font_family),
                    'text_menu_font_size' => self::cleanHTML($text_menu_font_size),
                    'text_menu_font_weight' => self::cleanHTML($text_menu_font_weight),
                    'text_column_title_font_weight' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_title_font_weight),
                    'text_column_title_font_weight' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_title_font_weight),
                    'text_column_title_font_style' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_title_font_style),
                    'text_column_title_font_size' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_title_font_size),
                    'text_column_title_font_family' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_title_font_family),
                    'text_column_list_font_style_hover' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_list_font_style_hover),
                    'text_column_list_font_weight_hover' => self::cleanHTML($text_column_list_font_weight_hover),
                    'display_flags' => $display_flags,
                    'default_language' => $default_language,
                    'languages' => $languages
                ));

            $dir_tpl = dirname(__FILE__);
            if ($ajax)
            {
                   $output['configure'] = $this->display(__FILE__, 'edit_element.tpl');
                    $output['configure'] = $this->context->smarty->fetch($dir_tpl . '/tpl/edit_element.tpl');
                    $output['view'] = $this->viewMenu($menu->id);
            }
            else $output = $this->display(__FILE__, 'tpl/edit_element.tpl');
                //$output['configure'] = $this->context->smarty->fetch($dir_tpl . '/tpl/edit_element.tpl');

            return $output;
    }
```

The ajax param is true for default, i would like why the display function resturns false,viewMenu return null, the view menu function is:

```
public function viewMenu($id_menu)
    {
            if (!is_numeric($id_menu))
                    return;

            $id_menu = (int)$id_menu;
            $menu = new Innovative_menu($id_menu);

            return '<fieldset>
                            <legend>'.$this->l('Preview :').' '.$menu->name.'</legend>'.$menu->view().'
                    </fieldset>';
    }
```

The display function in Module.php is like that:

```
public function display($file, $template, $cacheId = null, $compileId = null)
{
    if (($overloaded = Module::_isTemplateOverloadedStatic(basename($file, '.php'), $template)) === null)
        return Tools::displayError('No template found for module').' '.basename($file, '.php');
    else
    {
        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'module_dir' =>             __PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.basename($file, '.php').'/',
            'module_template_dir' =>    ($overloaded ? _THEME_DIR_ : __PS_BASE_URI__).'modules/'.basename($file, '.php').'/'
        ));

        if ($cacheId !== null)
            Tools::enableCache();

        $result = $this->getCurrentSubTemplate($template, $cacheId, $compileId)->fetch();

        if ($cacheId !== null)
            Tools::restoreCacheSettings();

        $this->resetCurrentSubTemplate($template, $cacheId, $compileId);

        return $result;
    }
```

It should return the tpl edit_element but it returns false.
Thanks in advance.